# How to get number of likes from facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How to get number of likes from facebook like button?
Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 26):

There are two ways to get the number of facebook likes.

1. Graph API

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3a%2f%2ffacebook.com

Result is JSON: (For some reason 'likes' are called 'shares')

```js
{
   "http://facebook.com": {
      "id": "http://facebook.com",
      "shares": 35641554,
      "comments": 339
   }
}
```

2. FQL

http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url="http://facebook.com"'

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
  <link_stat>
    <total_count>35641554</total_count>
  </link_stat>
</fql_query_response>
```

Comment: Reason this called shares is probably cause of statements on [Like Button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), read **What makes up the number shown on my Like button?** section

Comment: Do you know the limit/ the number of links you can get stats of in only one request? I need this information in my design but cannot find it in the documentation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FQL won't be available anymore from August 2016: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/