# PHP: Custom Liking Function for my Comics Site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a comics website and have recently been working on and testing a liking function. The reason I'm building my own is because

1. I wanted to allow users to like and dislike a comic. FB liking doesn't offer that
2. I wanted a custom liking graphic
3. I want the like counts to be stored in my database so I can sort
   comics by popularity... I don't think I can get the total likes from
   FB for such a thing.

Based on the information below, should I continue on with my approach or not?

Each time a unique person likes a comic id, it will first insert that user's ip and that specific comic id that they liked.

Since their IP is now in the database, if they try to vote on the same comic id again, it won't let them. But their IP can still vote on any other comic id.

If they are in fact liking a unique comic id, it will increment the like or dislike count of the associated comic id in the comics table. I can then use this to rank and sort comics by popularity.

As I was testing, I realized that a user with a unique IP can potentially like all comics (ex: 127.0.0.1 liked comicid  30, 127.0.0.1 liked comicid 31, 127.0.0.1 liked comicid  32, etc... and there's 60 unique comics)... so that's 60 database entries. That's just one user... Now what happens if my site starts becoming popular... that could result in n voters * x comics that they've liked... which could be a ton of database entries... which could be a huge burden on my hosting server, and a mess to manage.

That being said, should I just use facebook's liking function? If I do that, can I use those likes to rank my own comics by popularity in the database? Should I continue on with my custom liking function, but change my approach?

If it'd be helpful, I can post my current liking function code...

Any tips appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: Why not just implement the facebook like feature?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija 1) I'm not sure how do use total facebook like for a particular comic id to sort my comics by popularity, and 2) When I reload the page (a new comic id is loaded because user pressed next img or something), the facebook comments weren't being associated with that new id... idk how to fix this

Comment: What if multiple users login via the same IP and try to like _the same comic_ again? Will you reject all except the first?

Comment: @Pushpesh for example, you mean several users at a netcafe using the same computer try to like my comics? I haven't thought about that... and I don't know what a good solution is

Comment: Yes, net cafe, users behind a proxy in a office...like that..you can do a combination of IP and sessionID to restrict the user voting activity on a particular comic, imo.

Comment: @Pushpesh Okay, cool. So what do you think about actually managing the likes in a database? If FB liking is more worth it, when the user loads the next image... how do I reload the correct likes associated with that new comic id?

Comment: @Growler I'd be shooting in the dark if i tell you something about the proper way to do it as i haven't done anything similar. I was just trying to point out an obvious use case you missed in your flow. Hopefully, other SO'ers will pitch in with more detailed howto's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd stick with the facebook like button. As you can see from the comments it can get tricky to think of all the cases if you're trying to do it yourself, but FB has already taken care of that.

The FB API definitely allows for getting the number of likes, take a look at this related post: [How to get number of likes from facebook like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931104/how-to-get-number-of-likes-from-facebook-like-button)